# Dataflow flex template: ModuleNotFoundError: no module name

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My Python package has the following structure with `beam.py` being the entry-point script for Dataflow:

```
package_name\
    __init__.py
    tasks\
        __init__.py
        package_sum.py     
    utils\
        __init__.py
        beam.py
.gitignore
requirements.txt
setup.py
Dockerfile
```

`beam.py`:

```py
import argparse

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

from package_name.tasks import package_sum


def run(input_pubsub_topic, beam_args):
    beam_pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
            beam_args, 
            save_main_session=True, 
            streaming=True
    )

    # Initialize the Beam pipeline
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=beam_pipeline_options)

    pipeline | 'ReadFromPubSub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(input_pubsub_topic)
             | 'Sum' >> beam.Map(package_sum)

    # Run pipeline
    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="test")
    parser.add_argument("--input_pubsub_topic")

    args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    run(args.input_pubsub_topic, beam_args)
```

In my `Dockerfile` below, I install the package in the image as well as download it to `/tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache`:

```bash
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base:latest

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY package_name package_name

# Do not include `apache-beam` in requirements.txt
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/package_name/utils/beam.py"

# Install apache-beam and other dependencies to launch the pipeline
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]==2.32.0
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir . \
    # Download the requirements to speed up launching the Dataflow job.
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache .

# Since we already downloaded all the dependencies, there's no need to rebuild everything.
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True
```

When I launch the flex template job, it still results in the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package_name'`. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `setup.py`?

Answer (score 2):

For the flex template to recognize `package_name` you need to define `PYTHONPATH` on your Dockerfile. Add this line in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH ${WORKDIR}
```

Your final Dockerfile should look like:

```
FROM gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base:latest

ARG WORKDIR=/dataflow/template
RUN mkdir -p ${WORKDIR}
WORKDIR ${WORKDIR}

COPY requirements.txt .
COPY package_name package_name

ENV PYTHONPATH ${WORKDIR}

# Do not include `apache-beam` in requirements.txt
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE="${WORKDIR}/requirements.txt"
ENV FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_PY_FILE="${WORKDIR}/package_name/utils/beam.py"

# Install apache-beam and other dependencies to launch the pipeline
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir apache-beam[gcp]==2.32.0
    && pip install --no-cache-dir -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    && pip install --no-cache-dir . \
    # Download the requirements to speed up launching the Dataflow job.
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache -r $FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_REQUIREMENTS_FILE \
    && pip download --no-cache-dir --dest /tmp/dataflow-requirements-cache .

# Since we already downloaded all the dependencies, there's no need to rebuild everything.
ENV PIP_NO_DEPS=True
```

Make sure to rebuild both the image and flex template prior to running the Dataflow flex template.

Comment: Thanks @Ricco, I tried `ENV PYTHONPATH ${WORKDIR}`, however that did not work. Then I tried setting `FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES` as an environment variable and that worked. Would you know why `PYTHONPATH` didn't work but `FLEX_TEMPLATE_PYTHON_EXTRA_PACKAGES` did? 
I also don't understand why I need to specify any of these environment variables since the package is already installed in my Docker container (I can see it when I run `pip list` in the container), and I thought the workers workers would be using the same container and pip environment.

Comment: @aaron02 I see, you can post your answer as well and accept it. With regards to you follow up question, it might be better to create a new question for it so the community can possibly provide an answer.

Answer (score -1):

import name is wrong, according to your project structure you don't have `package_sum`

try this

```
from package_name.tasks import sum as package_sum
```

Note:  Use a meaningful naming convention for your modules and packages, otherwise, you can't find the real error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however that was a typo in the question. I have now corrected the file name from `sum.py` to `package_sum.py` which is what I have and still face the `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: I'm sorry hard to investigate, with the given info. Maybe someone will help you if you update the full error log.